# UNION with ORDER BY RAND() works only with LIMIT on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I put this together on SQLFiddle and it works as intended, but on the university MySQL engine, it works differently: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d975f/3

I have a list that contains words and their categories:

```
id, word, category
1, red, color
2, blue, color
3, brick, item
4, rock, item
5, hat, item
6, glove, item
7, cape, item
8, cup, item
9, love, feeling
... etc
```

I need 8 words, where the first 4 are a mix of colors and items, but the last 4 are only items, and the words must be randomly selected and unique.

For example: blue, hat, rock, red, brick, glove, cup, cape (color, item, item, color, item, item, item, item)

I could not do this in a single query, so I first ran a query to get a list of IDs for the first half, for example, 1, 2, 4, 5 (red, blue, rock, hat)

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM word WHERE id IN (1, 2, 4, 5) ORDER BY RAND()
```

Always giving me words 1, 2, 4 and 5 in random order.  However when used in a UNION as a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM word WHERE id IN (1, 2, 4, 5) ORDER BY RAND() ) a 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM word WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2, 4, 5) AND category='item' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4) b
```

The first 4 words are ALWAYS in order, giving me, for example: 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 3, 7, 6.  However, if I specify the limit:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM word WHERE id IN (1, 2, 4, 5) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4) a 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM word WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2, 4, 5) AND category='item' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4) b
```

It works EXACTLY as intended.  I get red, blue, rock, and hat in random order, followed by 4 more items in random order, not including rock and hat.

I understand UNION has a list of rules to remove duplicates, but I'm confused as to why including the limit would change the behavior.

Ideally, I would like to get this done in a single query, but I couldn't figure out how to do a NOT IN on the 2nd half of a union that refers to words selected in the 1st half of a union.

Comment: You could always randomise the order of the result set - either with a super query or in application code

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, `UNION` has a deduplicating function. This function often works with a hash merge. It nullifies the effect of any `ORDER BY` clauses in the subqueries contributing to the merge.  (Some DBMSs say "you can't use `ORDER BY` in a subquery bound for a `UNION`", but MySQL lets you do it.)

You could try something like this to work around the problem.

```
SELECT word
   FROM (
       SELECT word, RAND() random FROM word WHERE  id IN (1, 2, 4, 5) 
       UNION
       SELECT word, 1.0+RAND() random FROM word WHERE id NOT  (1, 2, 4, 5) 
   ) w
  ORDER BY random
```

This will do the ordering in the outer query, not the subquery, and will achieve the kind of ordering you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. This disables the duplicate suppression feature of `UNION`, and will probably keep the order coming from the subqueries.